# how to get list of devices for class device with only getter and parameterize constructor

Tags: c#

I am traversing the Xdocument and getting the attribute value for device name and IP and would like to get a list of device with device name and IP.

My Device class has only getter and  parameterize constructor,

```
 public class Device
{
    private string _deviceName;
    private string _ip;
    public Device(string ip, string deviceName)
    {
        _ip = ip;
        _deviceName = deviceName;
    }

    public string DeviceName
    {
        get { return _deviceName; }

    }

    public string IP
    {
        get { return _ip; }
    }
}
```

And here is the code to generate the list of devices, currently it has error, what we need to do here,

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            string testData = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
                                <SSPReturnMessage>
                                        <DeviceList>
                                            <Device SN=""RX1"">
                                            <PL N=""XYZ"" Vn=""PQR""/>
                                            <IP> 192.168.201.248 </IP >
                                           <DN><![CDATA[device name]]></DN>
                                            </Device>
                                        </DeviceList>
                                </SSPReturnMessage>";

            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(testData);

            var devices = xDoc.Descendants("Device")
            .Select(x =>
                new Device
                {
                    DeviceName = x.Element("IP").Value,
                    IP = x.Element("DN").Value,

                }).ToList();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you assign wrong values to ip and device name...

Comment: then where to add, please suggest, current code has compile error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an [object initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) instead of just using the regular constructor you've defined in your `Device` class. Like this:

```
var devices = xDoc.Descendants("Device")
        .Select(x =>
            new Device (x.Element("IP").Value, x.Element("DN").Value))
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string testData = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
                                <SSPReturnMessage>
                                        <DeviceList>
                                            <Device SN=""RX1"">
                                            <PL N=""XYZ"" Vn=""PQR""/>
                                            <IP> 192.168.201.248 </IP >
                                           <DN><![CDATA[device name]]></DN>
                                            </Device>
                                        </DeviceList>
                                </SSPReturnMessage>";

                XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(testData);

                var devices = xDoc.Descendants("Device")
                .Select(x =>
                    new Device
                    {
                        DeviceName = x.Element("IP").Value,
                        IP = x.Element("DN").Value,

                    }).ToList();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
    public class Device
    {
        private string _deviceName;
        private string _ip;
        public Device() { } //added
        public Device(string ip, string deviceName)
        {
            _ip = ip;
            _deviceName = deviceName;
        }

        public string DeviceName
        {
            get { return _deviceName; }
            set { _deviceName = value;}  //added

        }

        public string IP
        {
            get { return _ip; }
            set { _ip = value; }  //added
        }
    }
}
```